# How to run procedure every week till end date in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a procedure which I need to execute every week from the date of deployment in production.It should run on the day of deployment and then subsequent weeks till the end date which is stored in a variable.

I need to incorporate this at procedure level rather than creating separate scheduler or dbms_job

Suppose the start date is 11/1/2013 (day of deployment) and end date is 04/30/2014
I need to run the procedure every week once between this to period including the start date.

Suppose the proc run on 04/28/2014 and next week falls in MAY,  then till 4/30/2014 it should run each day.

help will be appreciated.

```
    BEGIN

        FOR I IN (SELECT typename ....)-- will give 3 output
        LOOP
        IF typename = 'ABC' THEN
       -- run THE UPDATE every week FROM start date TO END

            UPDATE  TEST
                    SET TEST.A = ....,
                        TEST.b = ....
                    WHERE TEST.c IN (....)

        ELSIF typename = 'PQR'THEN 
             UPDATE  TEST1
                    SET TEST.A1 = ...,
                        TEST.b1 = ...,
                    WHERE test1.c IN (....)  
         END LOOP;
         END;                 
     -- run THE UPDATE every week FROM start date TO END 

     --Note start date and end date is different for different types.

     --***If the week it ran is less than end date then schedule the update every day from --that week
     --eg the last day ends at 04/30/2014, , 
--the last run happened on 04/28/2014 then update should run on 4/29,4/30 also
```

Comment: "I need to incorporate this at procedure level"  what does this mean?  Why is dbms_scheduler forbidden? (it was created to do what you want, schedule db tasks)

Comment: I have 3 blocks in my proc.with different end dates,so I would need to create three schedulers.This proc will be called by another procedure.So I was thinking of implementing in the procedure rather than scheduler.

Comment: I use scheduler often.  Its unclear what your situation is, but I doubt you need 3 separate scheduler jobs (perhaps a chain, but again, unclear).  Can you post some code of what you're trying to launch?

Comment: Ok I will post the code

Comment: Is there anyway of setting up something similar to SSIS but for an Oracle db?

Comment: If this is being done in a business context it is inconceivable to me that you would not make use of whatever scheduling product is used at your site. If I found this being done in the software at my place of work I would immediately notify my supervisor because, believe me, *I* ain't gonna be the guy standing in the security director's office explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what Bob Jarvis commented, but if you still need to solve your problem , one possible solution is to use dbms_lock.sleep( Number_of_seconds ); ,
so a basic pseudocode would be :

- run your DML statements
- calculate number for seconds in a week
- use dbms_lock.sleep( Number_of_seconds ); to suspend the procedure
- repeat until end date is equal or less than SYSDATE.

see more information about that procedure in [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:836514322495)